# Can i make an internal Q&A site like StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking forward to develop a Q&A site that was requested to be private for my company, and as my boss talked it looked like he was describing StackOverflow, what i want to know is, is it possible to develop a private Q&A site like this using the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The API gives read-only access (for now) to the Stack Exchange network of sites.  It doesn't provide any services for constructing similar sites.