# Using Stack API for a Forum?

Tags: discussion

I don't know if this is the right stack site to ask this...

Would it be possible to build a forum using the stack API?  Would it even make sense?

Comment: Is your question similar to [this one](http://stackapps.com/questions/1930/can-i-make-an-internal-qa-site-like-stackexchange)?

Comment: I guess so.  Seems the API cannot be used to create your own Stack based site/sub-site.  Am I right?

Comment: That's right - however, if you have an idea for a 'Stack-based site', then consider heading over to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) and submitting it.